# Django, How to get ONLY the latest data save in the database?

Tags: python, django

I have two models, PurchaseOrder and PurchaseOrderdetail, I just want to know how do i get the latest record save in the PurchaseOrder  by filtiring the PurchaseOrderdetail ,

this is my models.py

```
class CustomerPurchaseOrder(models.Model):
      ....
      inputdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="OrderSubmittedDateTime")
      ....

class CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail(models.Model):
      ....
      customer_Purchase_Order = models.ForeignKey(CustomerPurchaseOrder,
                                            on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                            verbose_name="CustomerPurchaseOrder")
```

this is my views.py

```
allrelatedProduct = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.filter(profile__in=client.values_list('id')).latest('customer_Purchase_Order__inputdate')
```

this is the error i get

```
'CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail' object is not iterable
```

my full traceback

```
Template error:
In template C:\Users\USER\Desktop\LastProject\OnlinePalengke\customAdmin\templates\customAdmin\clientAdmin.html, error at line 341
   'CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail' object is not iterable
   331 :   <h1>My Account</h1>
   332 : 
   333 :   <div class="grid">
   334 :     <div class="grid__item medium-up--two-thirds">
   335 : 
   336 :       <div class="content-block">
   337 : 
   338 :         <h2>Order History </h2>
   339 : 
   340 :     <div class="scrollable-container">
   341 :  {% for history_product in allrelatedProduct %} 
   342 : 
   343 :           <table class="responsive-table cart-table">
   344 :           <thead class="cart__row visually-hidden">
   345 :             <th colspan="2">Product</th>
   346 :             <th>Quantity</th>
   347 :             <th>Total</th>
   348 :           </thead>
   349 :           <tbody id="CartProducts">
   350 :               <tr class="cart__row responsive-table__row">
   351 :                 <td class="cart__cell--image text-center">


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\LastProject\OnlinePalengke\customAdmin\decorators.py" in wrapper_func
  42.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\LastProject\OnlinePalengke\customAdmin\views.py" in client
  124.                "allrelatedProduct": allrelatedProduct})

File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  165.                 values = list(values)

Exception Type: TypeError at /client/
Exception Value: 'CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You're using `latest()` method which returns the last object in the queryset. And you are using a for loop wich can't be used since `allrelatedProduct` will be just an object and you can't iterate over an object.

Comment: then how do i print it in the html?

Comment: Answered with full details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the `CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail` objects related to the latest `CustomerPurchaseOrder`:

```
last_order = CustomerPurchaseOrder.objects.order_by('inputdate').last() 
# or .order_by('-inputdate').first()

# you can add more filters like: user=user_obj
allrelatedProduct = CustomerPurchaseOrderDetail.objects.filter(customer_Purchase_Order=last_order)
```

Now if you want to render all the results:

```
{% for history_product in allrelatedProduct %}
    <p>history_product.inputdate</p>
{% endfor %}
```

but if you want just one:

```
<p>{{allrelatedProduct.first.inputdate}}</p>
```

you can also get the one object you need in your view and pass it to the template and remove `.first` so it can just be called using `allrelatedProduct.inputdate`